# Cuda programming reducing with complete unrolling without _syncthreads()

Tags: cuda

Recently, I am read the book *Professional CUDA C Programming* and I find the following part of coding that I do not fully understand.

[image]

I am confused about the final part of coding which deals with the unrolling warp. I know that this part of coding tries to reduce the loop consume and the times of calling `_syncthreads()`. However, I do not understand how this can make sure the order of add operation. For example, I think all threads should do `vsmem[tid] = vsmem[tid + 16]` after `vsmem[tid] = vsmem[tid + 32]`. I do not know how to make sure that. It seems that there is no synchtreads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason there is no need of `_syncthreads()` is that the processors will have 32 concurrent [warp threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_block#Warps). These are ensured to execute simultaneously in the GPU, they happen at the same time, so no need to "wait" or synchronize.

[This presentation](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) (page 21) has a more thorough explanation.

Comment: But you shouldn't rely on this behaviour, as it can change in the future.

Comment: Using an active group and syncing them should result to no-op on warp-synchronous devices